# Magento: How to check which payment method has been selected?

Tags: php, magento

I need to check, if 'paypal' is the selected payment method before the review order stage, as if it is, I need to fire some code.

What's the best way to find out the 'selected' payment method, once it has been saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
```